# Update Realm primary key value swift

Tags: ios, database, swift, realm

Im using Realm for my iOS app and for a table i have a primary key "name"

```
                let application  = Application()
                application.domain = app.domain
                application.name = app.name
                realm.add(application)
```

now when it try to update the name it throws an error

```
app?.name = newName
```

the error is

```
Primary key can't be changed after an object is inserted.
```

How do i solve this problem ?

this is how I declare the primary key

```
override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "name"
    }
```

Comment: Can you please show us declaration of your primary key?

Comment: @VishalSonawane i updated the question on how i declare the primary key

Comment: Your Primary key is the name. You can't change the primary key. You can delete the object and create a new one

Comment: @Idan damn!! are you sure ? I can totally do this in sqlite

Comment: It is pretty simple to remove and add an object in realm. Four lines of code and you are done.

Comment: @Idan yeah i know but still.. anyway thanks for the help (y)

Comment: You dont need to use primary key if it can be changed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you insert an object with a `primary key` you cannot modify it:

From [Realm Docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#updating-objects)

> primary key is added to a Realm, the primary key cannot be changed.

Which leave you with few options:

- Remove and reinsert the object
- Change the primary key to something that doesn't change, like `id`
- Omit the `Primary Key`. If you don't define one, you don't have a primary key, which means you can have more than one object with the same value for this property and it won't be indexed by this property.

Comment: This does work because the crash happens as soon as i set `app.name=newName` before even doing a `realm.add`

Comment: I ended up removing and adding new object. but this got me in the problem where the object has relations. making all those relations nil

Comment: Just hold the relations locally for the transfer.

Comment: Realm doesn't automatically pick primary keys. If you don't define one, you don't have a primary key, which means you can have more than one object with the same value for this property and it won't be indexed by this property.